# Send auto-repeated key using CoreGraphics methods (Mac OS X Snow Leopard)

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, core-graphics, macos-carbon

I have been successful sending keystrokes in order to automate a particular software package for drawing that I use. This software relies a lot of keyboard shortcuts so I wrote something that could call some of these keyboard shortcuts in order to streamline my workflow. As I said, this has worked out good.

My library is a Cocoa library that is loaded as a plugin to the software package. Here is a snippet of code that I have been using for sending my keystrokes.

```
CGEventSourceRef eventSource = CGEventSourceCreate(kCGEventSourceStateHIDSystemState);
CGEventRef eventDown = CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent(eventSource, (CGKeyCode)1, true);
CGEventRef eventUp = CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent(eventSource, (CGKeyCode)1, false);

//setting the process number somewhere else
CGEventPostToPSN(&number, eventDown);
CGEventPostToPSN(&number, eventUp);
```

For some procedures in the drawing package if you continue to hold the Shift key then you activate a special tool. I have been unable to simulate this. I thought I could send the Shift key and say that I wanted it to auto-repeat but that doesn't seem to work. I have been using the following code to set the auto-repeat:

```
//This is done before sending the key
CGEventSetIntegerValueField(eventDown, kCGKeyboardEventAutorepeat, 1);
```

In my testing I have been unable to make any key auto-repeat. It just send the key once and that is it.

Is there anyone that have been successful autorepeating a key using the above method? I have searched the Internet for answers but all I have found are some unanswered questions from 2008... Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

mobbe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code that OP finally came up with to solve the problem (transferred here from a comment under other answer):

```
CGEventRef flagsChanged = CGEventCreate(eventSource); 
CGEventSetType(flagsChanged, kCGEventFlagsChanged); 
CGEventSetIntegerValueField(flagsChanged, kCGKeyboardEventKeycode, 56);     
CGEventSetFlags(flagsChanged, 131330); 
CGEventPostToPSN(&number, flagsChanged); 
CFRelease(flagsChanged); CFRelease(eventSource);
```

`131330` is a constant indicating the Shift key; it is related to `NSShiftKeyMask` and `kCGEventFlagMaskShift`, which are `131072` (`0x00020000`). `131330 - 256 - 2 == 131072`.

Comment: Thanks for all your help. It was interesting to learn more about the event system.

Comment: Regarding the magic number I think I need to do some more digging. I got that number by printing out the event when a shift key was delivered to other applications (Using [NSEvent addglobalmonitorforeventsmatchingmask). It is related to the ShiftMask but there is something else in there as well...

Comment: @mobbe: You're quite welcome! Nice work on the solution! I saw `131330` while testing too. The best candidates I can come up with for the other two flags are `NX_DEVICELSHIFTMASK = 0x02`, which is the "device-dependent" left shift mask, and `NX_NONCOALESCEDMASK = 0x100`. I'm not sure what that one does.

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE: the Shift key's code isn't `56`, according to Events.h:

```
...
kVK_Shift                     = 0x38,
...
```

(EDIT: of course those of you who are paying attention (I wasn't) realize that HEX 38 == DEC 56.)

I also realized how to get modifier key presses: `flagsChanged:`. So using this keycode, I can catch Shift key presses in `flagsChanged:`, and the repeat works fine; I also get repeated key events for "normal" keys in `keyDown:` and `keyUp:` without difficulty.

It sounds like you may not have access to/want to change the event-handling code (to add `flagsChanged:`) though, so if that keycode doesn't work for you, I'm stumped and can only say "Good luck!"

---

I believe that the field you're setting is used to indicate not that the event should *be* repeated by the system, but that an event *is* an auto-repeat of a previous event. You still have to generate each event yourself. Something like (EDITED to use a timer instead of a loop):

```
CGEventSourceRef eventSource = CGEventSourceCreate(kCGEventSourceStateHIDSystemState);
CGEventRef eventDown = CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent(eventSource, (CGKeyCode)1, true);
// Post the initial keydown
CGEventPostToPSN(&pidNumber, eventDown);

// Keep track of how many Shift keydown events have been sent
shiftKeyRepeatCount = 1;
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.3    // I don't know exactly what the interval should be, of course
                                 target:self
                               selector:@selector(repeatShiftKeyDown:)
                               userInfo:nil
                                repeats:YES];

CFRelease(eventDown);
```

---

```
- (void)repeatShiftKeyDown:(NSTimer *)tim {
    if( shiftKeyRepeatCount >= kRepeatCountForSpecialTool ){
        [tim invalidate];
        [self sendShiftKeyUp];
        return;
    }
    shiftKeyRepeatCount++;
    GEventSourceRef eventSource = CGEventSourceCreate(kCGEventSourceStateHIDSystemState);
    CGEventRef eventDown = CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent(eventSource, (CGKeyCode)1, true);
    // Set the auto-repeat field
    CGEventSetIntegerValueField(eventDown, kCGKeyboardEventAutorepeat, 1);
    CGEventPostToPSN(&pidNumber, eventDown);
    CFRelease(eventDown);
}
```

I'm not certain whether you can reuse the first event with a changed field or you'll need to generate a new event to use when repeating.

Comment: Thanks for you suggestion. Unfortunately it doesn't seem to work for me. Still only one character is being sent to the app...at least that is what it looks like. I tried both with creating a new event just for the repeat as well as reusing my original keydown...

Comment: Try a repeating timer with a short interval instead of a loop. It occurred to me after I posted that the `for` loop will go as fast as possible, which would be faster than the event system would generate events for a physical key press; the events may just get dropped. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Still only one character coming through. I tried a couple of different time intervals but it doesn't seem to make a difference. If you see different results on your computer please let me know.

Comment: @mobbe: Bummer. I'm far from an expert on this; I'll try to test it out later and get back to you. Wish I could be more helpful.

Comment: Oh, one other thing: are you sure that `kCGEventSourceStateHIDSystemState` is the right value? The docs say <quote>If your program is a daemon or a user space device driver interpreting hardware state and generating events, you should use this source state when you create an event source.</quote> The other option is `kCGEventSourceStateCombinedSessionState`, which looks like it may be better for faking key presses.

Comment: Tried the other event source and same result. I really do appreciate your efforts. I am surprised that there seems to be no real easy way of doing this...

Comment: After more testing it looks like you can't even send a Shift down via the method I am using. If I specify a character like say 's' then that is sent to the application (but only once)...however there seems to be no way to just tell the application that Shift was pressed...you always have to have another character and the Shift as a modifier. I have tried to send the character 56 which is suppose to be Shift but the application never recognizes this....

Comment: @mobbe: There is a way to catch a Shift key down by itself; there are games that do it. I just don't know what that way is. I was also wondering whether Shift might be a key that the system wouldn't accept auto-repeat for. I haven't gotten to try this out yet. Hopefully someone with more knowledge will chime in. You might try posting a message to the cocoa-dev list, too: http://lists.apple.com/mailman/listinfo/cocoa-dev If you get a response there, you can just post your own answer here!

Comment: @mobbe: added a bit to my answer. Hope it's helpful.

Comment: Actually 0x38 and 56 comes out to be the same number..hex vs decimal. I too discovered that it is flagschanged that is the key here...cool that you did to. Here is the code for simulating a shift key press using code: CGEventRef flagsChanged = CGEventCreate(eventSource);
    
    CGEventSetType(flagsChanged, kCGEventFlagsChanged);
    
    CGEventSetIntegerValueField(flagsChanged, kCGKeyboardEventKeycode, 56);
    
    
    CGEventSetFlags(flagsChanged, 131330);
    
    CGEventPostToPSN(&number, flagsChanged);

    CFRelease(flagsChanged);
    CFRelease(eventSource);

Comment: The 131330 code might look like magic but it just a flag for the shift modifier. The header files and documentation have the constant that should be used instead for better readability

Comment: @mobbe: Re: 0x38 == 56 -- I feel like an idiot for saying that! I was in such a rush trying variations on this code out, it hardly even registered that it was hex. Anyways, glad it's solved.

Comment: @mobbe: I'm going to transfer that code to a Community Wiki answer. I'm not quite sure what the constant name is: `NSShiftKeyMask` and `NX_SHIFTMASK` are 131072, which is 131330 - 256 - 2. Please edit the answer to clarify when you get a chance, or post your own answer -- no reason you can't do that, and give it the checkmark instead, since it's the real solution to your problem.